# How to download and update local images under monotouch app

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a question regarding how to update local images embedded as content in the application.

My application is built using 30 images stored as "Content" (embedded in the app) for a image gallery that I have to show. Every 2 days the application check server info to see if the images have been changed in the database, in that case then I have to compare files and if any file has changed then I have to download it and update the local image.

I have read the the best way to store images for this kind of porposses is under "Library" folder of the application, but the images that comes with the app are built as "Content" (embedded)...

Any clue on the best way to do that in monotouch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resources, like images, that you bundle inside your .app becomes part of your application. Since the application is signed you **cannot** update (or remove) those files as it would invalidate the signature (there's also file permissions that won't allow this to happen).

*note: it can work in the iOS simulator since it does not require (or check) for application signatures, however it won't works for application on devices.*

What you can do is:

1. Bundle default images with your applications;
2. Download new images (when needed) and install them outside your application ([in the appropriate directory](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Application_Fundamentals/Working_with_the_File_System));
3. Have your application checks if there are downloaded images (or if images needs to be downloaded) and fallback to the images that ships with your application;

Comment: Thanks @poupou, Im trying to use https://github.com/Redth/MonoTouch.UrlImageStore to download multiple images but dont really know exactly how to use that library have you used it before?

Comment: No I have not. There's some sample code linked from the README that might help. Also the code does the *right* thing since it calls `Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath (Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))` to select where to store the images it downloads.

Comment: Thanks, was reading that apple will reject the app if images are stored in Documents because then it will sync to cloud or itunes.

Comment: Apple could reject it, that depends on what are the image. There's a directory defined for **caching** data (that won't get backed up in the cloud). However if this becomes **user data** (e.g. if it's modified and becomes unique) then it's should be backed up and parts  of the document directory. So it's really app specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change any file from your app (they're read-only).

What you can do is to save the files to a read-write directory, and at runtime check if those images are there (and not then use the ones bundled with the app).